# Performance for selecting from current year

Tags: postgresql, date, where-clause, query-performance

I know lots of ways of doing this like

```
date_field > firstday and date_field < current_date
date_part('year',date_field) = date_part('year',current_date)
```

And a few other. Currently, a script we use goes the first example, used to count stuff from the first day of the year till now, but the 1st day of the year is hard coded. Query takes around 2.4 seconds to complete.

I thought I'd change it and make something like the second way, but then the query takes around 19.7 seconds to complete. I thought I'd go another way...

```
date_field > to_date(to_char(CURRENT_DATE,'YYYY')||'-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
and date_field < CURRENT_DATE
```

This drops the query to 1.5s. I tried googling around but found nothing about the performance of all these different options, thought I'd throw it around here for my betters to help enlighten me.

Comment: compare execution plans - I bet `>` will use index and `date_trunc` will not

Comment: I would NOT recommend an approach that applies a function to the data e.g. `date_part('year',column_here)`  removes access to any index on that column

Comment: ...unless there's a function index. But yes, it's usually a lot faster and easier if you compute the actual starting and ending points and compare your date/time to that rather than try to convert each date/time to see if it matches a condition.

Comment: suggest: `date_field >= date_trunc('year',CURRENT_DATE) and date_field < CURRENT_DATE` *not sure why you have not been using >= on the lower date*

Comment: for performance tuning use **explain plans**

Comment: well, considering most of my pgsql knowledge comes from online web classes and stackoverflow, you can probably understand why I had no idea on any of the comments =) thanks, I'll check those out!